# Trouble installing IPython 2.2.0 on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, ipython

I tried installing IPython on Windows 7 with the specific point of being able to try out the IPython notebook.  After a few false starts and problems, I eventually to things sort of working, the IPython console comes up ok, but when I run "ipython notebook" I get the following:

```
C:\Users\dude102438\Downloads> ipython notebook
2014-09-13 16:57:13.861 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\\Users\\dude102438\\.ipython\\profile_default'
2014-09-13 16:57:13.979 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-09-13 16:57:14.062 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\dude102438\Downloads
2014-09-13 16:57:14.062 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
2014-09-13 16:57:14.062 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2014-09-13 16:57:14.062 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 788
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 340, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 788
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 788
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 340, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 788
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 788
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 340, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 788
```

(... the error loops infinitely)

I first tried installing IPython by dl'ing ipython-2.2.0.zip, running 'setup.py install', then running 'ipython notebook' and waiting for the dependency errors to come up, which they did.  First pyzmq, which I tried to pip install, but I don't have the MS VC setup, so finally found the windows installer at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs.  Then tornado, which installed smoothly.  Then I had this problem.  I manually uninstalled (deleted files in Python27/Lib/site-libraries and Python27/Scripts) and tried installing ipython‑2.2.0.win32‑py2.7.exe (from Gohlke page) and reinstalling pyzmq, but still the same results.  I did have RabbitMQ installed, so got rid of that, but still same results.

Appreciate any ideas, thanks.

Comment: Try the latest version of pyzmq. The version you are using is several years old.

Comment: Thanks, nice catch.  I'm not sure how or where I got the initial pre-compiled pyzmq, but I got the latest off the Gohlke page, that did the trick.